# Creating test data in database for tests

Tags: spring, hibernate, junit

I want to write test for my project (spring+hibernate), and for tests I use in-memory databese  (hsqldb). And I need to fill my database with some data. As for me the best way to do it is using @BeforeClass method. Something like this

```
@Transactional
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:test-applicationContext.xml")
public class UsersControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() {
            User u = new User();
            u.setLogin("test_login");
            u.setPassword("test_password");
            u.setName("test_name");

            Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            session.save(u);
    }
```

But I can't do this because sessionFactory will be null in this case. It will work if I use @Before method instead @BeforeClass. But I think it's not a good solution, because this method will run before every @Test method and I don't need it.
So my question is simple. What solution will be the best for this situation when you need to create test data in database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about simply using a static boolean flag to prevent the code in the `@Before` method from being repeatedly executed. Something like this:

```
public class UsersControllerTest {

    private static boolean isDataSetLoaded = false;

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        if (!isDataSetLoaded) {
            loadDataset();
            isDataSetLoaded = true;
        }
    }

    private void loadDataset() throws Exception {
        // save various entities here
    }
}
```

#### Update:

I would like to draw your attention to a caveat of the above solution that just caused me serious headache:

The `@Transactional` support is implemented in a very counterintuitive  way by Spring. I would expect that transactions are opened just before entering the test methods, but in fact they are already opened at an earlier stage: even before the `@Before` annotated methods are executed.

This means that any data manipulation in `loadDataset()` will run inside the same transaction as the first test method, which is a *huge* problem, because the default behavior of `@Transactional` test methods is to roll back at the end. The net result is that all initialization steps in `loadDataset()` are undone after the firts test method, so subsequent test methods will fail if they rely on the prepared data.

Of course, this is only an issue if the operations in `loadDataset()` are willing to join an existing transaction, which can be prevented by applying the appropriate transaction attributes (e.g. using a `TransactionTemplate` with `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW`).

Comment: As there are no other suggestions I'll use yours. Thanks!

Comment: Just made an update to my answer, please check it above in order to avoid unexpected problems.